# abi.map not a function error trying to connect to uniswap

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ethers.js, uniswap

I'm new to working with blockchain and I'm having a problem trying to get the contract from Uniswap. I've been following their docs on V3 but I can't get past this "abi.map is not a function" error. When I output the ABI to the console, it looks like I get the ABI back correctly but when I try to use it to initialize the contract I get this error.

```js
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
const ABI = require('@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol/IUniswapV3Pool.json')
console.log(ABI)

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/Your Address Here;p')
const poolAddress = '0x8ad599c3A0ff1De082011EFDDc58f1908eb6e6D8'
const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(poolAddress, ABI, provider)

interface Immutables {
  factory: string 
  token0: string
  token1: string 
  fee: number
  tickSpacing: number
  maxLiquidityPerTick: number
}

async function getPoolImmutables() {
  const [factory, token0, token1, fee, tickSpacing, maxLiquidityPerTick] = await Promise.all([
    poolContract.factory(),
    poolContract.token0(),
    poolContract.token1(),
    poolContract.fee(),
    poolContract.tickSpacing(),
    poolContract.maxLiquidityPerTick(),
  ])

  const immutables: Immutables = {
    factory,
    token0,
    token1,
    fee,
    tickSpacing,
    maxLiquidityPerTick,
  }
  return immutables
}

getPoolImmutables().then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: If it expects abi.map to be a function, then it must expect abi to be an array (and it isn't).  Check https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1238

Comment: I've tried the fix they suggest there and get back module cannot be found. Ive check the file directory and the module is there and im point to the right place.

Answer (score 3):

This error will go away if you delete everything in the abi up to the first square bracket after "abi". So for IUniswapV3Pool.json, instead of:

```
{
  "_format": "hh-sol-artifact-1",
  "contractName": "IUniswapV3Pool",
  "sourceName": "contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol",
  "abi": [
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
...
```

It should be:

```
[
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
```

And don't forget to delete everything up to the last square bracket at the end of the file as well.

Answer (score 3):

To build on @jaspers answer you don't actually need to delete anything from the original file. you just need to pass the abi property from the original.

```
const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(poolAddress, ABI.abi, provider)
```